# Как заставить код вычислять слово и не игнорировать остальные индексы

Tags: python, строки, поиск, подстрока

```
text = ("In the above example, we have created "
        "a function named find_square()."
        " The function accepts a number and returns the square of the number.")
gir = input()
q = (text.find(gir))

def lo():
    x = 0
    for i in text:
        if gir in i:
            x += 1
    print(x, q)
lo()
```

Проблема вот в чем, написал программу где пользователь должен ввести определенную букву, а программа говорит сколько этой буквы в тексте сверху.

Так же создал чтобы программа выяснила индекс нахождения буквы.

Мне хочется сделать так, чтобы:
Код обращал внимание на то сколько слов в тексте
Чтобы индекс не игнорировал остальные буквы, а не вывел первую найденную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример, как посчитать количество вхождений подстроки в строку и вывести все индексы найденных позиций:

```
text = ("In the above example, we have created "
        "a function named find_square()."
        " The function accepts a number and returns the square of the number.")
gir = input('Введи часть слова ')

entries = []
start = -1

while True:
    start = text.find(gir, start+1)
    if start == -1:
        break
    else:
        entries.append(start)

if (len(entries) > 0):
    print(f'Количество вхождений: {len(entries)}, позиции подстроки: {entries}')
else:
    print('Ничего не найдено')
```

т.е. мы пробегаемся по строке, если нашли вхождение, то запоминаем позицию и повторяем поиск с данной позиции, до тех пор, пока не вернется -1(ничего не найдено).

Найденные позиции сохраняем в список

Comment: спасибо, то что надо было

Answer (score 0):

Это можно эффективно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений

```
import re

text = ("In the above example, we have created "
        "a function named find_square()."
        " The function accepts a number and returns the square of the number.")
gir = input('Введи часть слова: ')

positions = [m.span()[0] for m in re.finditer(re.escape(gir),text)]
print(f'Сочетание букв `{gir}` найдено {len(positions)} раз(а) в позициях {positions}')
```

```
Введи часть слова: he
Сочетание букв `he` найдено 4 раз(а) в позициях [4, 71, 113, 127]
```